# How to find Substring in Java using Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a String called `String mainString = "/abc/def&ghi&jkl";`
I need to find the substring using Regex in java. The Substring will be `lastindexof("/") and indexof("&")` i.e. `def`.
How can I do that using Regular Expression in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
(?<=\/)(?=[^\/]*$).*?(?=&)
```

- `(?<=\/)` - Positive lookbehind to match positions that are right after a forward slash.
- `(?=[^\/]*$)` - Positive lookahead with a negated character class to match anything but a forward slash zero or more times followed by the end string position.
- `.*?` - Match any character other than newlinge zero or more times but lazy (read up to the next).
- `(?=&)` - Positive lookahead to match position in string that is followed by a `&`.

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSOrGB/1/)

<sup>**Note:** You may swap the positive lookahead for a negative lookahead as mentioned by @CarySwoveland: `(?<=\/)(?!.*\/).*?(?=&)`. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSOrGB/2)</sup>

---

A second option is using a capture group (as per @TheFourthBird):

```
/([^/&]+)&[^/]*$
```

Where:

- `/` - Match a literal forward slash.
- `(` - Open capture group.

  - `[^/&]+` - A negated character class matching anything other than forward slash or ampersand at least once.
  - `)` - Close capture group.
- `&` - A literal ampersand.
- `[^/]*` - A negated character class, matching anything other than forward slash zero or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LMk0Vd/2)

---

Also I am not sure you'd need regular expressions at all. I've no experience with Java whatsoever but pieced this together with some googling:

```
public class Tst{    
     public static void main(String []args){
        String mainString = "/abc/def&ghi&jkl";
        String[] bits = mainString.split("/");
        String subbit = bits[bits.length-1].split("&")[0];
        System.out.print(subbit);
     }
}
```

Which returns: `def`

<sup>**Note:** Or even as a one-liner with nested `split` commands: `System.out.print(mainString.split("/")[mainString.split("/").length - 1].split("&")[0]);`</sup>

Comment: ...or, in place of your first lookahead, `(?!.*\/)`.

Comment: Yes @CarySwoveland, thats maybe even a little faster? I've added it in =) Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Or perhaps also use a capturing group `/([^/&]+)&[^/]*$` https://regex101.com/r/LMk0Vd/1